# Custom html site converted in to wordpress, email form php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, email

I am a beginner in html/wordpress css js.

I managed to convert my html site in to wordpress but on my html i had a php email form which was working fine in html but not in wordpress, 
any idea what code i need and where to place?
here is the html:

```
<section id="contact" class="text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="2000">
                    <h3>CONTACT US</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <p>Contact us today </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <form action="emailform.php" method="post">
                    <div class="col-md-4 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="2000">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="2000">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="2000">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="2000">
                        <textarea placeholder="Message" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="2000">
                        <input type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with you should use the name attribute on all of your inputs.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp

Also if the file is stored within your theme you need to use

`<form action="<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/path/to/file/emailform.php" method="post">`

Comment: Thats ok i understand the inputs, but my real issue is making the form work in wordpress, php?

Comment: which file? my emailform.php file? yes it is in the directory and when i click submit i kept getting blank white screen.

Comment: so you are using `<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>`? Make sure the file is in the root of your "theme" folder and use `<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/emailform.php`

Comment: I would also recommend using the plugin contact form 7 https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/ which you can give classes and style how you like :)

Comment: i prefer my own form, i also did try that form but i was not receiving the emails in the inbox,but for now im using formget. It would have been better if i could have got my form to work.

Comment: may b i need some code in functions.php..i dont know not sure

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>http://mysite.CO.UK/baca2ztheme/wp-content/themes/mytheme/emailform.php" method="post">
```

thats the url and now when i click on submit its as it refreshes the page. but if i manually refresh the page it says browser is trying to send information click ok to resend etc...